# How can I access unistd write from another scope?

Tags: c++, unistd.h

I am trying to use unistd.h write from inside a class where another "write" function has been declared, but I don't know which is the scope resolutor I should use, as unistd is not a library, so unistd::write() won't work.

How can I call it from inside the function?

```
// this won't compile

#include <stdio.h> // printf
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 


class Fifo {
public:
    void write(const char* msg, int len);
};

void Fifo::write(const char* msg, int len) {
    int fd; 
    const char* filename = "/tmp/fifotest"; 
    mkfifo(filename, 0666); 
    fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK);
    write(fd, msg, len); 
    close(fd); 
}   

int main() 
{ 
    Fifo fifo;
    fifo.write("hello", 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So use the unnamed scope `write`. The

```
write(fd, msg, len);
```

is equal to

```
this->write(fd, msg, len);
```

`write` resolved to `Fifo::write` inside `Fifo` function. Do:

```
::write(fd, msg, len);
```

to use global scope. like:

```
#include <cstdio> // use cstdio in C++
extern "C" {      // C libraries need to be around extern "C"
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
}
class Fifo {
public:
    void write(const char* msg, int len);
};
void Fifo::write(const char* msg, int len) {
    int fd; 
    const char* filename = "/tmp/fifotest"; 
    mkfifo(filename, 0666); 
    fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK);
    ::write(fd, msg, len);  //here
    close(fd); 
}   
int main() { 
    Fifo fifo;
    fifo.write("hello", 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Research scopes, namespaces and scope resolution operator in C++ for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had never seen the "unnamed scope" and I was blocked looking for a library to point the write() to.